# Spring Boot: Who to write a custom Prefilter, considering the user role?

Tags: rest, security, spring-boot, filter, user-roles

I need some kind of `@preFilter` (or, if it isnot possible than  `@postFilter`) to filter the results of my REST API. I can not use the `preFilter`anotation, because I need to consider the user role. I have three different roles:

- `user` the normal user, who shold only access data which he owns
- `teamleader` this role should access all data of his team
- `admin` who can access all data.

Because our database structure is really complex, it will be necessary, to access some other data, before I can decide if the user can access the requested data or parts of the requested data.

The snippet works only for the roles `user` and `admin`. For teamleader it will be more complex, then there will be a bunch of `masterDataId` which have to be connect with `or`.

Here is some pseudocode, hopefully its not to confusing:

```
public class RoleFilter {

    DimensionAttributeValueRepository dimensionAttributeValueRepository;


    public void doFilter(Collection<AllDatas> data) {
        if (user.getRole() != "admin") {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            DimensionAttributeValue tmpValue = dimensionAttributeValueRepository.findByChrValue(auth.getUsername());

            MasterData masterData = tmpValue.getMasterData();

            data.filter(data.masterDataId == masterData.getMasterDataID());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update: Example**

Lets say I have two users, user A is a normal user with the role "user". User B is an admin with the role "admin".

There is a Database table, in which the `userData` are stored. The table looks like the following.

```
| ID | username | name | email |
```

Both of them are sending a simple **authenticated** `GET` request to `/userData`.

Now my backend detects based on the `authentication` header the users and add the roles.

Nwo depending on the role, the user A should only get an answere which contains his personal data, user B should get all data which are accessible though `/userData`.

Response for user A:

```
{
   "res":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "username":"userA",
         "name":"A",
         "email":"userA@mail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Response for user B:

```
{
   "res":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "username":"userA",
         "name":"A",
         "email":"userA@mail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "username":"userB",
         "name":"B",
         "email":"userB@mail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "username":"userC",
         "name":"C",
         "email":"userC@mail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase I would recommend to use a custom filter and integrate it into the `spring-security` filter chain. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter) is a tutorial, explaining it in general. You could configure your custom filter so that it checks your complex roles against the database and then overwrite the current users authentication object with a new one.

**Example implementation:**

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {
            // HERE GOES YOUR CODE

            // Depending on the extracted authentication details of the current user, you can now overwrite the users GrantedAuthorities

            Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> oldAuthorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TEAMLEADER");
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
            updatedAuthorities.add(authority);
            updatedAuthorities.addAll(oldAuthorities);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(     
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(),      
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials(),
                updatedAuthorities));

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can check for your roles with this statement: `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_TEAMLEADER')")`

Then you can just access the users roles with the help of the `spring-security-context` object: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

Based on its results you can now customize your answer upon the roles that are stored in this object. You could for example implement a RestCall on `/userData` like this:

```
@GetMapping("/userData")
public List<Object> getUserData() {
  List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roles = (List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
  SimpleGrantedAuthority authorityTeamLeader = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TEAMLEADER");

  List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

  if (roles.contains(authorityTeamLeader)) {
    result = getAllUsers();
  } else {
    result = getPersonalUser(roles);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But if I understand you correctly, this will not lead to a solution of my problem. I know the user roles, the problem is, I like to return a different set of data, depending on the role.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Again thanks, but still won’t lead to a solution. let me clarify the problem a little bit more. I have that user roles and I have also implemented something similar like your code do check which kind of user sends the request. I will update my original post with an example. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: I have added the example

Comment: I have added another example implementation of a custom Get-Controller